# playing byte[] using naudio

Tags: c#, naudio

1. How can I convert an audio file to byte[] and play it using Naudio? (code will be appreciated)
2. Also related to question above, how to play audio file in Resource using Naudio?
   For the second question I have this code:

   ```
   IWavePlayer waveOutDevice;
   IWaveProvider provider;

   public void PlaySound(byte[] sound)
   {
     waveoutDevice = new WaveOutEvent();
     provider = new RawSourceWaveStrem(new MemoryStream(sound), new WaveFormat();
     if (waveOutDevice != null)
     waveOutDevice.Stop();
     waveOutDevice.Init(provider);
     waveOutDevice.Play();

   }
   ```

   In my form constructor I then do something like -

   ```
   PlaySound(Properties.Resources.beepsound)
   ```

   beepsound being the sound file....but I just hear a noise when this method is called. What could be wrong?

Comment: you can play sounds directly with naudio. you dont need to convert files into byte[] yourself

Comment: I know sound files can be played directly but in my case I need to convert to byte[] to avoid the processor going on the hard disk to search for the file.

Answer (score 1):

The `WaveFileReader` class can accept a `Stream` as a parameter, so you can use a `MemoryStream` to encapsulate a `byte[]` buffer whose contents you have loaded from a file.

Something like this:

```
byte[] fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Some\File.wav");
var waveFileReader = new WaveFileReader(new MemoryStream(fileContent), true);
```

You can use `GetManifestResourceStream` or similar to get a stream for a resource and use that.  If you want to reuse the streams, pass `false` as the second parameter which will stop them being disposed along with the `WaveFileReader` instance.