# How to play WAV file from Embedded Resources with NAudio?

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm using C#, WPF, and [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) to play a `wav` file.

I have `sound_1.wav` in the Resources folder and included in project. Once compiled, it exports the exe and resources to a folder and plays the wav from a path on the hard drive.

```
string sound1 = "Resources\\sound_1.wav";

NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader wav = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(sound1);
WaveOutEvent output = new WaveOutEvent();
output.Init(wav);
output.Play();
```

---

But I would like to embed the `wav` file in the `exe` and use something like:

```
UnmanagedMemoryStream sound1 = Properties.Resources.sound_1; //embedded resource
NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader wav = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(sound1);
```

[image: Embedded Resources]

How can I get that to play through `WaveFileReader`? It only accepts `string` path.

---

#### Solutions

This works, but the sound plays in slow motion and sounds like reverb.

```
UnmanagedMemoryStream sound1 = Properties.Resources.sound_1;

WaveIn wavin = new WaveIn();
NAudio.Wave.RawSourceWaveStream wav = new NAudio.Wave.RawSourceWaveStream(sound1, wavin.WaveFormat);         
WaveOutEvent output = new WaveOutEvent();
output.Init(wav);
output.Play();
```

---

This works with loud pop at the end of sound.

Convert Stream to Byte Array
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1080445/6806643

```
byte[] b = ReadToEnd(sound1);

WaveStream wav = new RawSourceWaveStream(new MemoryStream(b), new WaveFormat(44100, 16, 2));
WaveOutEvent output = new WaveOutEvent();
output.Init(wav);
output.Play();
```

Comment: Have you tried [extracting the embedded resource to a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412401/how-to-read-an-embedded-resource-as-array-of-bytes-without-writing-it-to-disk) & then [creating a WaveFileReader using a MemoryStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33954614/playing-byte-using-naudio)

Comment: @PaulF It still seems to require a string path.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - WaveFileReader accepts a Stream as a constructor - this can be a MemoryStream created from a byte array. You create the byte array by extracting the embedded resource.

Comment: @PaulF They use `String filename`. When I change it to `UnmanagedMemoryStream filename` to extract the embedded resource it still requires `String` for `a.GetManifestResourceStream(filename)`.

Comment: @MattMcManis: doesn't it work to pass sound1 to GetManifestResourceStream like in the first link PaulF (accepted answer by Rotem) has provided?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the embedded file through Properties.Resources.sound_1 --- _"NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader wav = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.sound_1), true);"_

Comment: @PaulF Error: `cannot convert from System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream to init`

Comment: @PaulF I updated my post, at the bottom is some code that almost works.

Comment: What do you mean by "almost works"?

Comment: @PaulF It had some audio popping and artifacts. I managed to figure it out, but it has really high RAM usage. https://stackoverflow.com/q/49186932/6806643

Comment: @PaulF Here is the solution I came up with, still with problems. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49191890/6806643

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to make it work.

The problem with this solution is high memory usage.

#### WAV

```
// embedded resource sound.wav

UnmanagedMemoryStream sound = Properties.Resources.sound;

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(StreamToBytes(sound));

WaveStream ws = new WaveFileReader(ms);

WaveOutEvent output = new WaveOutEvent();

output.PlaybackStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(Media_Ended);
output.Init(ws);
output.Play();
```

---

#### MP3

```
// embedded resource sound.mp3

MemoryStream sound = new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.sound);

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(StreamToBytes(sound));

WaveStream ws = new Mp3FileReader(ms);

WaveOutEvent output = new WaveOutEvent();

output.PlaybackStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(Media_Ended);
output.Init(ws);
output.Play();
```

---

#### Stream to Byte Array

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1080445/6806643

I used this to convert `MemoryStream` to `byte[]`, or else it will crash if 2 sounds play at the same time with `Exception "Not a WAVE file - no RIFF header"`.

---

#### Dispose

Doesn't seem to have any affect on reducing RAM.

```
public static void Media_Ended(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (output.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Stopped)
    {
        if (ms != null)
        {
            ms.Close();
            ms.Flush();
        }
        if (ws != null)
        {
            ws.Close();
        }
        if (output != null)
        {
            output.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may need to call Dispose for each of the stream instances as they all implement IDisposable.

Comment: @PaulF I tried calling `Close()` and `Dispose()` in `Media_Ended()`. That way it doesn't close a sound as it's playing. But the memory usage never goes down.

Comment: Yeah, I can put it in `Media_Ended()` after every key press, but it's overkill. Made no difference. Here the yellow line show when GC is called. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mat1a.jpg

Comment: also try setting output to null and clearing the stopped event handler which could be keeping alive the wave out, which in turn is keeping alive the input stream

Comment: @MarkHeath How can I clear the stopped event handler? It says it's ReadOnly if I do `output.PlaybackState = null`.

Comment: you can do `-= new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(Media_Ended);`

Comment: @MarkHeath Where should I put that, Before `output.Init()`, after `output.Play()` or in `Media_Ended()`?

Comment: @MarkHeath Or just replace the `+=` one with `-=`?

Comment: What is `StreamToBytes`??

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution for that, which also works with .aif and aiff files and does not require to split .mp3 and .wav files. It can be done using the `AudioFileReader` class, but this class does not support `Stream`s, just file paths. However, we can skip this issue by using some reflection to create an `AudioFileReader` instance with a `Stream`. Just paste the code somewhere in your code:

```
namespace NAudio.Extensions
{
public static class Extensions
{
    public static AudioFileReader GetAudioFileReaderFromStream(Stream stream, string fileExt)
    {
        try
        {
            AudioFileReader reader = (AudioFileReader)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(AudioFileReader));

            // this is how the constructor looks
            //lockObject = new object();
            //FileName = fileName;
            //CreateReaderStream(fileName);
            //sourceBytesPerSample = readerStream.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample / 8 * readerStream.WaveFormat.Channels;
            //sampleChannel = new SampleChannel(readerStream, forceStereo: false);
            //destBytesPerSample = 4 * sampleChannel.WaveFormat.Channels;
            //length = SourceToDest(readerStream.Length);

            Type type = reader.GetType();
            type.GetField("lockObject", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(reader, new object());
            var readerStream = GetWaveStream(stream, fileExt);
            type.GetField("readerStream", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(reader, readerStream);
            var sbps = readerStream.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample / 8 * readerStream.WaveFormat.Channels;
            type.GetField("sourceBytesPerSample", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(reader, sbps);
            var sampleChannel = new SampleChannel(readerStream, forceStereo: false);
            type.GetField("sampleChannel", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(reader, sampleChannel);
            var dbps = 4 * sampleChannel.WaveFormat.Channels;
            type.GetField("destBytesPerSample", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(reader, dbps);
            var std = dbps * (readerStream.Length / sbps);
            type.GetField("length", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(reader, std);

            return reader;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static WaveStream GetWaveStream(Stream stream, string fileExt)
    {
        WaveStream readerStream = null;
        if (fileExt.Equals(".wav", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            readerStream = new WaveFileReader(stream);
            if (readerStream.WaveFormat.Encoding != WaveFormatEncoding.Pcm && readerStream.WaveFormat.Encoding != WaveFormatEncoding.IeeeFloat)
            {
                readerStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(readerStream);
                readerStream = new BlockAlignReductionStream(readerStream);
            }
        }
        else if (fileExt.Equals(".mp3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major < 6)
            {
                readerStream = new Mp3FileReader(stream);
            }
            else
            {
                readerStream = new StreamMediaFoundationReader(stream);
            }
        }
        else if (fileExt.Equals(".aiff", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || fileExt.Equals(".aif", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            readerStream = new AiffFileReader(stream);
        }
        else
        {
            readerStream = new StreamMediaFoundationReader(stream);
        }
        return readerStream;
    }
}
}
```

and then you can use it like this, just specify the file type (".wav", ".mp3", ".aif" or ".aiff"):

```
AudioFileReader reader = NAudio.Extensions.Extensions.GetAudioFileReaderFromStream(myStream, ".wav");
```