# High Memory Usage playing MP3's with NAudio on Key Press

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I'm using C#, WPF, and [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio).

I play an `embedded` resource `mp3` in the application `exe` when a key is pressed.

If a key is pressed repeatedly, RAM usage continues to climb past 400MB and never drops.

Using `Flush()` and `Dispose()` on the objects doesn't seem to free memory even when `GC` is called.

This did not used to happen when I played from `external` resource on the hard drive using `string` path instead of `MemoryStream`. It used to stay around 50MB RAM.

[image: memory usage]

---

```
public static MemoryStream ms = null;    
public static WaveStream wav = null;
public static WaveOutEvent output = null;

// Embedded Resource sound1.mp3
MemoryStream sound1 = new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.sound1);

// Key Press
//
if (e.Key == Key.Space) {
    ms = new MemoryStream(StreamToBytes(sound1));

    wav = new Mp3FileReader(ms);

    output = new WaveOutEvent();

    output.PlaybackStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(Media_Ended);
    output.Init(wav);
    output.Play();
}

// MP3 Playback Ended
//
public static void Media_Ended(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (output.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Stopped)
    {
        ms.Flush();
        ms = null;

        wav.Close();

        output.Dispose();
    }
}

// Convert Stream to Byte Array
//
public static byte[] StreamToBytes(MemoryStream stream)
{
    ...
}
```

Stream to Byte Array
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1080445/6806643

I convert to Byte Array back to a new Stream or the playback will not layer and will crash if 2 sounds play at once.

Comment: Try a using `using(ms = new  MemoryStream(StreamToBytes(sound1)) `block to dispose  and set sound1 to null after that block. I would like to see if that works as I am also new to using streams .

Comment: @MohamoudMohamed Each time a key is pressed: `System.ObjectExposedException Cannot access a closed stream`

Comment: When im using any stream I always use using statements around each and every resource that have try catch / if stream != null to move forward.Right know I think overtime you press a btn your using 3 resources and the garbage collector cant catch up. heres a good link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234059/is-a-memory-leak-created-if-a-memorystream-in-net-is-not-closed

Comment: @MohamoudMohamed I think it's closing the stream before the sound can begin playing. https://i.imgur.com/LXq8Fxh.png

Comment: I added this, it Disposes when sound has stopped. It runs smooth, but the memory usage is still high. Garbage Collector never drops it. https://i.imgur.com/wQ2y5ns.png

Comment: Yes remove the static null at the top  `public static MemoryStream ms = null; ` and use using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) , I dont want to tell you the wrong thing because Im new with streams too but overiding the behavior of dispose should use the disposable pattern..here is a link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166517/discussion-between-mohamoud-mohamed-and-matt-mcmanis).

Answer (score 1):

It's because you clicking space bar too fast :)

Each key click overwrites variables with new values. So when you click space bar 10 times in few seconds it will create 10 resources. But you keep reference to only last one created. When Media_Ended will start incoming, it will try to dispose only latest created resource.

Comment: Should I move `output.PlaybackStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(Media_Ended);` to another location? How should I dispose the resources?

Comment: @MattMcManis: Hmm... try cast sender to WaveOutEvent, then dispose.